# Installing virtualenv: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am following [this](https://github.com/mghildiy/cassandra-dtest#python-dependencies).

My mac machine has python 2.7, so I first installed python 3:

> brew install python3 libev

Then I installed virtualenv:

> pip install virtualenv

When I run:

> virtualenv --python=python3 --no-site-packages ~/dtest

...I get error:

> virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: --no-site-packages

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the virtualenv version is greater than 20, it is the default no site packages parameter

https://programmerah.com/solved-error-unrecognized-arguments-no-site-packages-29852/

Comment: 'If the version is greater than 20'...whose version?

Comment: I use the same words on the site, but I will fix it. I think it is a writing error, thanks. He is talking about virtualenv, --no-site-packages is default when the version is greater than 20